# How to set multi line header in react native?

Tags: react-native

I try to add a multi line title to my header like this:

```
    Title
  Subtitle
```

I tried the code below. It doesn't work, I got an error "title must be string or null"

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
    title: 
    <View>
    <Text>{navigation.getParam('client') }</Text>
    <Text>{navigation.getParam('ref') }</Text>
    </View>,
```

I followed this issue on github https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2430

Comment: Do you mean `headerTitle` instead of `title`?

Comment: Yes. I want my header title to be a multi line title

Comment: I meant that you should try replacing `title` with `headerTitle`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to replace `title` with `headerTitle` in order to provide the Custom Component.

The `title` prop accepts string values whereas the `headerTitle` defaults to a `Text` component that displays the `title`.

Therefore use it as

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: (
      <View>
        <Text>{navigation.getParam('client')}</Text>
        <Text>{navigation.getParam('ref')}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```